# Permission denied for the Kaniko job in openshift cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud, openshift, kaniko

I trying to do a deployment through my k8s operator on openshift 3.11 cluster. When the kaniko job starts it gives me the following error.

```
Error: error resolving dockerfile path: copying dockerfile: open /kaniko/Dockerfile: 
permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `securityContext: runAsUser: 0` into pod spec to run it as root.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
```

Comment: A short note about the security implications would be appreciated. This fix basically makes the process inside the container root on the host machine. This isn't necessarily bad, but CI pipelines tend to download lots of stuff (dependent packages) from the evil internet and execute them without thinking a lot. You should at least be aware of this fact.

Comment: Security implications: the UID of the user in that pod will be root. And once build is done, that pod would be gone, whatever was not pushed to a registry or whatever artifacts storage you use would be lost. Be that kaniko, buildah, docker, ... Make no mistake: if you want to build images, you will have to run that builder container as privileged. And addressing buildah being advertised as root-less, in OpenShift/Kubernetes: it will run as root. And if you can make it work as advertised, please contact RH support or tektonhub maintainers, as they're still looking for a working Task sample.

Answer (score 2):

Kaniko is being introduced as a tool to [Build container images in Kubernetes and Google Container Builder without privileges](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-kaniko-build-container-images-in-kubernetes-and-google-container-builder-even-without-root-access).

> we’re excited to introduce [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kaniko), an open-source tool for building container images from a Dockerfile even without privileged root access. With kaniko, we both build an image from a Dockerfile and push it to a registry. Since it doesn’t require any special privileges or permissions, you can run kaniko in a standard Kubernetes cluster, [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/), or in any environment that can’t have access to privileges or a Docker daemon.

The issue you are experiencing was already mentioned at [GoogleContainerTools/kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/681) GitHub issue.

On January 11 this issue was tagged as `Won't Fix` so the only way is to run Kaniko as root using `securityContext: runAsUser: 0`

This isn't secure as once would think, which is mentioned by [Kurt Madel](https://kurtmadel.com/) in his blog [Securely Building Container Images on Kubernetes](https://kurtmadel.com/posts/native-kubernetes-continuous-delivery/building-container-images-with-kubernetes):

> running as `root` is an attack vector that many consider to be an unacceptable security hole - but the use of Pod Security Policies will reduce the attack surface of the Kaniko container running as part of a K8s Pod and provides greater security than the Docker based approaches we have already dismissed.

He also explains how one would use [Kaniko the Easy Way](https://kurtmadel.com/posts/native-kubernetes-continuous-delivery/building-container-images-with-kubernetes/#kaniko-the-easy-way)

> Jenkins X allows you to  [enable Kaniko as the default way to build and push container images](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/create-cluster/#the-jx-create-cluster-gke-process)  for all of your Jenkins X CD jobs and will be automatically configured to push to the default container registry of the cloud where you install Jenkins X and Kaniko caching is automatically set up for you - resulting in fast, secure container image builds that are pushed to your default Jenkins X container registry.
>
> **Important:**  Jenkins X does not have OOTB support for Pod Security Policies as tracked by  [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/1074). In my next post we will take a look at using Pod Security Policies with Jenkins X - but not just for Kaniko, because once you enable Pod Security Policy every K8s  `Role`/`ClusterRole`  has to have a Pod Security Policy associated to it.
>
> Drawbacks for Kaniko
>
> - Requires running the Kaniko container as  `ROOT`  to execute most container builds
> - Doesn’t work with all  `Dockerfiles`  but keeps improving
> - Is slightly more complicated to setup than the good old  `docker build`